# Batch To Find All Drive Letters Of Specific Path Mapping

Tags: batch-file

We had a script push out to map a new drive, but net use `R: /Delete` was not used so the drive is still there and there are incorrect mappings to the next available letter for hundreds of users.  I need to delete all incorrect mappings and was hoping there was a batch script that would scan for a specific mapping and then pipe the drive letter.

```
Set Path = \\Drive\Folder
Set DriveLetter = ?Scan all mapped drives for %Path%?
Net Use %DriveLetter% /Delete
```

Looking to fill in the blanks here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`net use` will show drive mappings (connected or not)

example output:

```
New connections will be remembered.


Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Disconnected Q:        \\Server1\Drive 
                                                 Microsoft Windows Network
OK           S:        \\Server2\Drive2 
                                                 Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.
```

looking at this output, the 2nd column, gives us the drive letter, and the 3rd gives us the path. putting this into a `for /f` loop to check the path, and if it matches delete the drive letter in the 2nd part

```
for /f "tokens=2,3" %%a in ('net use') do if .%%b==.\\Server\DriveCaseSensitive net use %%a /Delete
```

This means that it will also detect and remove mappings if the drive has been mapped multiple times

Comment: This will not work if the remote path includes spaces. I could not figure out a reliable solution that uses NET USE. It was fairly easy using WMIC NETUSE - see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13297306/1012053)

Comment: This worked like a charm.  It's standard practice not to have spaces in our mappings so we don't need to worry.

Answer (score 2):

Please do not use the PATH variable for your own purposes. It is a reserved variable, and using it for anything other than its intended use can wreak havoc on your batch session.

Here is a solution using WMIC that works. The backslashes must be escaped with another backslash when passed to WMIC. The check for a 2nd token is an artifact of how FOR /F treats the unicode output of WMIC.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "remotePath=\\Drive\Folder"
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%A in (
  `wmic netuse where "RemotePath='!remotePath:\=\\!'" get localName 2^>nul`
) do if "%%B" neq "" <nul net use %%A /delete >nul 2>&1 || net use %%A /delete
```

I'm not sure what is going on, but the first attempt to delete the mapped drive fails with the following message: *"There are open files and/or incomplete directory searches pending on the connection to n:."*. The second attempt succeeds.